# Getting java.time.DateTimeException when formatting LocalDateTime instance with Locale

Tags: java, java-time

This is not clear to me. For some reason when I am trying to format `LocalDateTime` instance using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(...)`, I am getting an exception:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class
>   java.time.LocalDateTime

It happens only if I am using `FormatStyle.LONG`, works fine for `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`, for example.

Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void dateTest() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    // this is ok. prints a value
    System.out.println("LocalDateTime now (formatted with locale): "
            + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                                                       .withLocale(new Locale("it"))));

    // this fails with java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.LocalDateTime
    // only if FormatStyle.LONG (as it is now)
    System.out.println("LocalDateTime now (formatted with locale): "
            + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
                                                       .withLocale(new Locale("it"))));
}
```

Is there any good explanation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

> Is there any good explanation for that?

Yes.

The `LONG` and `FULL` formats **requires a time zone** or offset-from-UTC. Your `LocalDateTime` **lacks any zone** or offset.

Your use of **`LocalDateTime.now` is incorrect**. You should only capture the current moment with `Instant` (or `OffsetDateTime`/`ZonedDateTime`).

```
Instant.now()  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

For more flexibility in generating strings, use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(
        FormatStyle.LONG   // Or `FULL`.
    )
    .withLocale( Locale.ITALY ) 
)
```

> 6 marzo 2019 10:22:23 NZDT

And, with `FormatStyle.FULL`:

> mercoledì 6 marzo 2019 10:23:25 Ora legale della Nuova Zelanda

## `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment

The `LocalDateTime` class is simply a date and a time-of-day. It purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So, by definition, it cannot represent a moment.

## Never call `LocalDateTime.now()`

> `LocalDateTime.now();`

Never do this, never call `now` on [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). I cannot think of any practical situation would ever call for that.

Never use `LocalDateTime` when tracking moments. A `LocalDateTime` is merely a date and a time-of-day, and nothing more. Without the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), a `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the current range of time zones around the globe.

A `LocalDateTime` is like saying “noon on the 23rd of January this year”. Do you mean noon in Tokyo Japan or Kolkata India? Or maybe Paris France? Montréal Québec? Noon in these various places happen at different moments, with hours elapsed between each.

The “Local” in `LocalDateTime` means *any* locality, or *every* locality, but does **not** mean any *particular* locality.

## Capturing the current moment

To track a moment, use one of these classes:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html)
  A moment in UTC, always in UTC
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)
  A moment with an offset-from-UTC, that is, a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of or behind the baseline of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (the meridian at [Royal Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich) in Greenwich).
- [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)
  A moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

Generally, best practice is to work in UTC and forget about your own parochial time zone.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

If you want to use the wall-clock time of some region:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( instant ) ;
```

Both the `instant` and the `zdt` represent the very same simultaneous moment, the same single point on the timeline. Only the wall-clock time is different.

Or you can skip the `Instant`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

## Formats `LONG` & `FULL` require a time zone

These two format styles:

- [`FormatStyle.LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG)
- [`FormatStyle.FULL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#FULL)

…both **require a time zone** as part of their display.

As discussed above, a `LocalDateTime` object has no zone or offset. So it makes no sense to use the `LONG` or `FUL` formats with such an object.

**Tip:** `LocalDateTime` is not often the class you want in most common business-oriented apps. Only use that class when you have a specific issue clearly in mind, such as booking appointments far enough out in the future that you run the risk of politicians redefining the offset of your time zone (which they often do, in most any polity). When tracking a specific moment, think first of using `Instant`.

Answer (score 3):

With `FormatStyle.LONG` You have to use :

```
ZonedDateTime.now()
```

Instead of :

```
LocalDateTime.now()
```

Because `ZonedDateTime` gives you lots of detail, not like `LocalDateTime`.

When you use `FormatStyle.LONG`, the formater search for other information like `ZoneId` which is not found in `LocalDateTime`, so you get exceptions